Pagination on nested Components Laravel Livewire
I want to make a pagination from a nested component on Laravel controller to Livewire but throws an error:

Property type not supported in Livewire for property:
[{"current_page":1,"data":[{"Id":3942,"Id_User":55,"Id_Desa":283,"Id_Kategori":6,"Nomor":"6","Tahun":2021,"Tempat_Penetapan":"Desa

this is my controller
'produk' => ProdukHukum::with('desas')->where('Id_User', $user)->orderBy('Tanggal_Pengundangan', 'desc')->paginate(10),

and sent to livewire components
<livewire:admin.tabel-produk-hukum :produk="$produk"/>

and this is the class for ProdukHukum
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Admin;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class TabelProdukHukum extends Component
{
    public $produk;

    public function mount($produk)
    {
        $this->produk = $produk;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.tabel-produk-hukum');
    }
}

is it possible to make a pagination form parent to nested components in Livewire?
Thank you

WithPagination must be used in the class where you implement the pagination. Manage the pagination in the parent class, manage the single row in the child class
